# Scrapy can't Login to BoardGameGeek

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to scrape data from BGG for a project but after the 20th page, you're required to log in. I'm following this [guide](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-build-a-home-server-for-data-analysis-on-board-game-data-using-raspberry-pi-scrapy-and-8a5839449c5a) and checked out some others that used Scrapy but this was before they implemented the login past a certain page. I can't seem to figure out how to get Scrapy's request functions to work.

I'm trying to use Scrapy's [Requests and FormRequest.from_response] in a Spider (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) as shown here:

```
class BGGSpider(Spider):
    name = "bgg"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://boardgamegeek.com/login/',
            callback=self.login
        )

    def login(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata = {
                'username': 'myname', 
                'password': 'mypassword',
            },
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
            url = "https://www.boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgame/page/"
            for index in range(1):
                yield Request(url=url+str(index+1), callback=self.parse_deeper, headers=self.headers, dont_filter=True)
```

and it returns " raise ValueError(f"No  element found in {response}")
ValueError: No  element found in <200 [https://boardgamegeek.com:443/login>"](https://boardgamegeek.com:443/login%3E%22)

but I checked the [login portal](https://boardgamegeek.com/login) and it looks like there's a form but I don't know how to get the requests to access it specifically or why it can't be found as a form (javascript embed maybe?). Help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

[the site has a form but I can't access it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXEXz.png)

Comment: There are some GitHub repos that I know contain these data. I am happy to share it with you.  It is fantastic if you still want to scrape bgg.

Comment: Hello @AlbertMarrero I'd love to see those if ever :>

Comment: Hello @keith, you can email me (my email should be in my profile), and happy to share them all. I don't want to clog the comments for something not related to your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right the page https://boardgamegeek.com/login/ doesn't not have the form for login, the real form is loaded via javascript, you can see the traffic of the web site using `inspect` on the chrome browser it really helps me on my work on https://bitmaker.la

the real url you have to post your login is https://boardgamegeek.com/login/api/v1 and you will receive a `204` status then you can go to https://boardgamegeek.com/?rnd=0mcmt and start scraping

here is a spider version of the explanation:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import json

class BGGSpider(Spider):
    name = "bgg"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://boardgamegeek.com/login/',
            callback=self.login
        )

    def login(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://boardgamegeek.com/login/api/v1',
            method="POST",
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter = True,
            body=json.dumps({"credentials": {"username": "username", "password": "password"}}),
            headers={
                'authority': 'boardgamegeek.com',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'origin': 'https://boardgamegeek.com',
                'referer': 'https://boardgamegeek.com/login',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
            }
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        url = "https://boardgamegeek.com/?rnd=0mcmt"
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_deeper)

    def parse_deeper(self, response):
        print("we passed the login")
```

BTW the `headers` are important

Comment: Omg this works thank you so much for this!! I remember seeing the api login [here](https://blog.arranfrance.com/post/board-game-geek-api/) but didn't know how to properly use it. Appreciate your help!